# Build warning _GetPrimaryCpuAbi target -> Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(311,2): warning : One or more errors occurred

Tags: c#, xamarin, msbuild

I have a strange effect that I get a build warning after I worked on my project.

I don't know who it happens. Maybe after I updated some nuget packages. But the warning is still strange for me.

The **diagnostic build output** shows the following nformation:

```
1>"D:\Dev\Root\Projects\App\AGVIPSQL\Droid\AGVIPSQL.Droid.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
1>(_GetPrimaryCpuAbi target) -> 
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(311,2): warning : One or more errors occurred.
1>
1>    1 Warning(s)
1>    0 Error(s)
```

Does anybody knows how to get rid of this warning.

Searching the internet I found this [bugzilla entry](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57016) but I can't see a solution and I can't see any relation to my project-.

Comment: What is the detail of the error/warning when you turn on MSBuild diagnostic level logging?

Comment: Please check the .csproj file. what .net common framework your project is using? Also you can build with different version of framework.

Comment: This is the diagnostic output!

Comment: The TargetFrameworkVersion shows v8.0. (Thats AFAIK Oreo) and the latest platform I have installed.

Comment: Please upload a full [Diagnostic Build Output](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/troubleshooting/#Diagnostic_MSBuild_Output) You can reference it in a Github Gist.

Comment: Here the [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/duv7ozee9v6g2ro/DiagnosticOutput.txt?dl=0)

Comment: It would be worth getting a `.binlog` to dig further in `Structured MSBuild Viewer` - http://msbuildlog.com/ From a quick look, it seems that the task is failing to get a value from device. This would be either a failed adb connection, or permissions to your device. Are you able to pull values from your device? For example `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for me restarting adb server was a solution.

```
Tools->Android->Restart Adb server
```